# How to make php output a link?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

The following code nicely outputs the column of users i have in a mysql database table in the browser.

```
<?php
$len = count($name);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
echo $name[$i];
echo "<p/>";
}
?>
```

However i would like each name to serve as a link to an external website.  The website corresponding to each $name[] in the array is on the same row in the same table.  So let us say that $name[0] has website w[0].

How on earth would i go about outputting the php in the browser so that each name linked to the corresponding website?  Many thanks in advance.  I hope i have been clear enough.  Cheers

Sorry, i should probably add the above that appears in my php script:

```
$name = array();
$w = array();
$i=0;
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($hof)){
$name[$i] = $result['username'];
$w[$i] = $result['website'];
$i++;
}
```

Comment: I've answered already in your other question. Why ask if you don't read answers?

Comment: You should give [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) a try. It makes a lot of things much easier than `mysql_` (which is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) btw).

Comment: as a matter of fact, PDO makes things more complex. Not to mention *user-defined functions*  (and classes) whose are *real* simplifiers.

Answer (score 2):

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($hof)){
    echo '<a href="'.$result['website'].'">'.$result['username'].'</a><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$len = count($name);
echo '<p>'
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
  echo '<a href="' . $w[$i] . '">' . $name[$i] . '</a>';
}
echo "<p/>";
?>
```

However, you should start learning some HTML basics before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go!

**Step #1**.

Mysql Users table exmaple:

```
ID  |  Username | Website
1   |  user_1   | user-1.com
2   |  user_2   | user-2.com
3   |  user-3   | user-3.com
```

**Step #2**

PHP

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("mhost", "muser", "mpassword", "databse");
if (! mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   $query = "SELECT Username,Website FROM Users ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

   if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
         echo '<a href="' . $row[0] . '">' . $row[1] . '</a>';
      }
      $result->close();
   }
```

Comment: mysqli just faster than mysql =)

Answer (score 0):

Easy just use ' instead of " in echo or string variable. Just like

<?php
echo ' [Power Point Website](https://powerpoint.base.pk)';
?>